# Uploading an artifact to Nexus from Jenkins on Cloudbees

Tags: nexus, gnupg, cloudbees

I want to upload an artifact from Jenkins running on Cloudbees to Nexus central, since my one is an OSS project stored in Maven Central. To do so, I need to install gpg keys locally. How can I do this on Cloudbees. I've done it on my local Linux box but I'd need access to some sort of Linux environment on Cloudbees.

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload your gpg key to your private repository on cloudbees forge, and set maven job to use -Dgpg.homedir=/private/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look into that. Erm, I don't have a private repository. Are you suggesting a code repository? Can I create one and still benefit from the FOSS programme?

Comment: Do you mean my private GPG key or the public one?